# Magento 2 setup with Multiple Stores and Domains

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, multidomain

I would like to setup multi store. 
I have two domains:

- example.com
- french.example.com

I use this article: 
https://www.simicart.com/blog/magento-2-multiple-stores-domains/
and created:

```
Websites:
French (Code: french) 
Main Website (Code: base) 

Stores:
French (Code: french)
Main Website Store (Code: main_website_store) 

Store views:
French (Code: french) 
Default Store View (Code: default)
```

Base URLs (Store View for Default config) is http://example.com.
Base URLs (Store View for French) is http://french.example.com.

It works correct!

But, I would like to use Base URL "example.com" for both domains!

I mean, that

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB)
```

have to return "example.com" for store view French as well!

Now it returns "french.example.com" for French and "example.com" for Default.

Is it possible to setup this way?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to set up another way.
I have entered for both domains Base URLs "http://example.com".

So, url for default sore view is:

```
http://example.com/default/
```

url for french store view is:

```
http://example.com/french/
```

But, I cannot setup, that http://example.com/french/ will redirected to http://french.example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make a Directory on root with name `french` and create file `index.php`
place below code in this file.

```
<?php
/**
 * Application entry point
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER; 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'french'; //Webite code as same in admin panel which we entered in step 2 
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'website'; 
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params); 
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */ 
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http'); 
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your solution, but I still have this issue.

Comment: did you place your code in ```html``` directory.

Comment: yes, I placed it to 'french/index.php'

Comment: strange i am using it with similar code. I have a multi website each with diff name.
check your base urls in ```core_config_data``` table